# How can I draw -X in the forest package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I want to draw a dead-end in `forest`. `edge={-X}` doesn't work.

Example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[$
    \begin{psmallmatrix}
      0 & ? & ? & ? \\
      ? & 0 & ? & ? \\
      ? & ? & 0 & ? \\
      ? & ? & ? & 0 \\
    \end{psmallmatrix}
    $
    [X] %[,edge(-X)]
    [$\begin{psmallmatrix}
      0 & 1 & ? & ? \\
      1 & 0 & ? & ? \\
      ? & ? & 0 & ? \\
      ? & ? & ? & 0 \\
    \end{psmallmatrix}$
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

I want something like this:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please do not link to external pages, if not really necessary. It would be helpful, if you add an image of your desired result. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear (at least to me) what you want to do. Can you please elaborate? If you could add an image (even hand-drawn) of the desired result, that would be great.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina i added picture

Comment: @Tonyko Thanks for the image, but where do you want that element to be attached to the tree? Should it appear as a leave, branching from the current "X", for example?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, I want to attach element "X" to the tree(edge) as in picture

Comment: @Tonyko Thanks! Now I understand what you want. I updated my answer below with the necessary code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the help of the `decorations.markings` library you can use a decoration for defining style to be easily applied to the desired "dead-end" edges. A little example (change the settings for the "x" mark according to your needs):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
  \tikz{
    \draw[thick] (-4pt,-4pt) -- (4pt,4pt);
    \draw[thick] (-4pt,4pt) -- (4pt,-4pt);
  }%
}  

\tikzset{
deadend/.style={
  decoration={
   markings,
   mark=at position 1 with \node {\usebox\mybox};
  },
  postaction=decorate
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[$
    \begin{psmallmatrix}
      0 & ? & ? & ? \\
      ? & 0 & ? & ? \\
      ? & ? & 0 & ? \\
      ? & ? & ? & 0 \\
    \end{psmallmatrix}
    $
    [\mbox{},edge={deadend}]
    [$\begin{psmallmatrix}
      0 & 1 & ? & ? \\
      1 & 0 & ? & ? \\
      ? & ? & 0 & ? \\
      ? & ? & ? & 0 \\
    \end{psmallmatrix}$
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As **Manuel** has noticed in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230136/how-can-i-draw-x-in-the-forest-package#comment543648_230141), if the "x" sign is is not needed to be upright, one can simply use the `Rays` arrow tip from the `arrows.meta` library:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[$
    \begin{psmallmatrix}
      0 & ? & ? & ? \\
      ? & 0 & ? & ? \\
      ? & ? & 0 & ? \\
      ? & ? & ? & 0 \\
    \end{psmallmatrix}
    $
    [\mbox{},edge={-{Rays[length=0.5cm,width=0.5cm,line width=1pt]}}]
    [$\begin{psmallmatrix}
      0 & 1 & ? & ? \\
      1 & 0 & ? & ? \\
      ? & ? & 0 & ? \\
      ? & ? & ? & 0 \\
    \end{psmallmatrix}$
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If the “X” is not needed to be upright, you could use an arrow tip from `arrows.meta` library.

Comment: @Manuel I added an example with the `Rays` arrow tip. Thanks, again.

Comment: May be a bit more appropiate with customization `[\mbox{},edge={-{Rays[length=.5cm,width=.5cm]}}]`.

Comment: @Manuel Sure. Done!